# Finding value in a text file

Tags: python, file, parsing, text

I have to find a value of a variable in a text file.

My file is in this form:

```
AccountingStoragePort=8544
AccountingStorageUser=root
Name=touktouk Cards=45 Files=2015 State=UNKNOWN
```

How to obtain for example the value of Files (thus 2015)

In this file there is either 1 "variable" / line or several separated by a space. Each value is unique (there are not 2 files in my file)

On the other hand, "Files" can be found at any line => at line 3 or line 150 for example.

I can not modify this file to be compatible with ConfigParser.

My conf file have comment who start with "#", I must exclude these line of my research.

for exclude comment line I try this but it's not work :

```
match = re.search(r"(?!#\s*)\bFiles=(\d+)", s)
```

I found the problem, if in my file I have return line, your code not apply comment restriction, for example:

```
import re

s = '''
AccountingStoragePort=8544                                               
AccountingStorageUser=root

#Name=touktouk Cards=45 Files=2015 State=UNKNOWN
Name=touktouk Cards=45 Files=2017 State=UNKNOWN
'''

match = re.search(r'^[^#].*\bFiles=(\d+)', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    value = match.group(1)
    print (value)
```

the program return 2015 not 2017

Comment: Parse the file line by line resetting when you think you are hitting a new node, and then it's a simple find word in line.

Comment: And what is a question? Just get a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.search`. If the value is number and variable occurs 1 time or less, use:

```
import re

s = '''AccountingStoragePort=8544                                               
AccountingStorageUser=root                                                      
Name=touktouk Cards=45 Files=2015 State=UNKNOWN'''

match = re.search(r'\bFiles=(\d+)', s)
if match:
    value = match.group(1)
    print value
```

Comment: Maybe use `r'\bFiles=(\d+)'` to make sure you don't get the value of a (hypothetical) key `OtherFiles`.

Comment: @RobinKoch, thanks, I think you comment is meaningful.

Comment: my problem is that file contains comment line (line start with #) can i exclude comment line of research group ?

Comment: @user7379681 if you want to exclude lines start with `#`, use `match = re.search(r'^[^#].*\bFiles=(\d+)', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: not work with my file, i have like this:
#NodeName=touktouk Getters=2 Files=1 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=touktouk Getters=4 Files=12 State=UP

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: @user7379681 I have tried and it's works perfectly. Give me a content of your file, with all lines.

Comment: I edit my first comment for explain my problem, because i can not to ident my code in this comment.

Comment: @user7379681 OK. If you have any questions, let me know

Comment: your # restriction not work if i have return line in my file, i edited my first post for explain this with an example.

Comment: @user7379681 Yes, I've see. Use `match = re.search(r'^[^#\n].*\bFiles=(\d+)', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 0):

A more

```py
import re
with open(file.txt) as f:
    kvlist = re.split(r'\s+', f.read())

pairs = [kvpair.split('=') for kvpair in kvlist]    
kvdict = {pair[0]:pair[1] for pair in pairs}

print(kvdict['Files'])
```

This should give you a complete dictionary for reuse on other values.